# Chances of runs.

Tags: probability

The following is an excerpt from my textbook:

> Suppose you pick $r$ numbers at random from a sequence of $n$ numbers. What is the probability that no two of them are adjacent, that is to say, the selection contains no runs? We just need to count the number of ways $s$ of choosing $r$ objects from $n$ objects in a line, so that there is at least one unselected object as a spacer between each pair of selected objects. The crucial observation is that if we strike out or ignore the $r-1$ necessary spacers then we have an unconstrained selection of $r$ from $n-(r-1)$...

That is $s= {{n-(r-1)} \choose r}$.

I understand that this can be applied to $n = 49, r = 6$. Then we can say that the number of ways of selecting 6 winning lottery numbers contains no runs at all is given by $ {44 \choose 6}$. I am struggling with the following examples

> **A run of 3**: Suppose we have 47 objects in a row. We can choose 4 of these with at least spacer between each in $${ 47+1-4\choose 4 } = { 44\choose 4 }$$ ways. Now we can choose one of these 4 and add two consecutive objects to follow it, in 4 ways. Hence the probability that 6 winning lottery numbers contain exactly one run of length three is $$4\frac{{ 44\choose 4 }}{{ 49\choose 6 }}$$

I have no idea why we are looking at $47$ objects and not $49$, and neither do I understand "Now we can choose one of these 4 and add two consecutive objects to follow it, in 4 ways"

> **two runs of 2**: Choose 4 non-adjacent objects from 47 is $${ 47+1-4\choose 4 } = { 44\choose 4 }.$$ Now choose two of them to be pairs in $$4 \choose 2$$ ways. Hence the chance that the 6 lottery numbers include just two runs of length 2 is $$\frac{{4 \choose 2}{ 44\choose 4 }}{49\choose 6 }.$$

Again, I do not understand why 47 is being used instead of 49. Also why are we choosing ${ 47+1-4\choose 4 } = { 44\choose 4 }$ instead of ${ 47+1-4\choose 6 } = { 44\choose 6 } $.

I am generally having problems in this area of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning a run of $3$.

---

Think backwards.

Suppose there is a sequence of $49$ of which $6$ are chosen and containing exactly one run of $3$.

Such a sequence might look like:

$\cdots\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\tag1$

How many are there?...

Well if we remove $2$ two bullets out of the run then we get a sequence of $47$ that looks like:

$\cdots\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\tag2$

So apparantly there is one-to-one correspondence between the sequences of form $(1)$ and of form $(2)$.

That is exploited because the number of sequences of form $(2)$ can be calculated as you describe in the first part of your question.

The same is true for sequences of length $49$ of form:

$\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\bullet\cdots\tag3$

In fact there are $4$ possibilities for the occurrence of the run and this explains factor $4$.